# Class visibility versus test cases

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that provides a library of related functionality to other groups within the company...

It recently became apparent that the library is being used by other groups in ways that makes it unstable - so my task is to limit scope of classes within the project so that only one singleton class is used as the entry point to the project.

**What I've done**
1) removed the "public" class modifier from "internal" classes
2) set methods to "protected"

**Result**
this update has been great because classes that are not meant to be exposed are now inaccessible outside of the project.

**HOWEVER**, the test cases are now not building due to the limited scope.

The person who wrote the test cases wrote the code in such a way that classes are instantiated individually and manipulated. This is no longer possible due to the limited scope (the test cases are in another package).

**Question**
To rectify this, should the test cases access the inner (private) classes through the singleton, or is there another way ?

Comment: Typically I put my tests in the same package as the class they are testing and make the methods I want to test package private.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot move the tests into the same package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your tests in the same package! If you want to keep them apart, just put them in another directory:

```
.
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── com.my.package
    └── test
        └── com.my.package
```

Comment: I set up the folder structure just like this, copied the test files, and it compiled

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be written in a way that facilitates your unit tests.  Internal implementation specifics not accessible via a public api are normally tested via your public apis.

Also, assuming we're talking about JUnits here, by convention your tests should be in the same package, not a different package. If there were, then even if your methods are default/package visibility, the tests in the same package can still access that code.

You should write your code in a way that makes it easy to test - if you find yourself doing things that seem far too hard, then you've most likely making it hard for yourself. Go back and look at the code again and see if you can refactor it to make it easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but out of due diligence I must echo what others have said and say that test classes should be in the same package. Any approach that differs from this will be painful. Either you will take longer to write the extra bit of code to access the inner class data or you will write code which is not testable. There is no benifit to not doing this that I am aware of or that you have stated.

What you have said about your library that users are easily writting code which is 'unstable' means that you have made some design errors in your API, nothing to be ashamed of we have all done that.

In addition it also concernes me the way you are talking about single point of entry and singletons. The most obvious use-case for singleton is for performing operations on a file. If you had multiple instances which had this prevallige you could have allot of locking going on and writting at the same time. I don't think the pattern is good for controlling how people use your library.

As hard as it is to say to me it sounds like you have some design flaws and that you have some particular problems you are trying to solve which are really just symtoms of these flaws, and cannot really be fixed any simple way.